# jQuery working in console but not in the website. Am also using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code in my view:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li role="presentation" ng-repeat='shop in shops'>
        <a ng-href="#{{shop.slug}}" ng-bind="shop.name" ng-click='selectTab(shop.id)'></a>
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- End of Navigation Pills -->

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" ng-repeat='shop in shops' id="{{shop.id}}">
        <table>...</table>
    </div>
</div>
<!--End of the Tab Contents -->
```

I am basically trying to make navigation pills that show certain `tab-pane` when clicked. I am using AngularJS directive `ng-click` with an `id` of the certain shop as the argument and using Bootstrap jQuery to acheive the result.

I have the following in my `app.js`

```js
$scope.selectTab = function(shop_id) {
    $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    $("#" + shop_id).tab('show');
}
});
```

When I use similar code in the console manually replacing the `shop_id`, the tab is being displayed. But the code is not working.

Please help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're executing jQuery code in the condole, the dom is fully loaded and all the resources are resent. Executing jQuery code in your javascript files may result in some runtime problems, so the code won't execute as expected. Wrap your jQuery code in the ready method, just like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $scope.selectTab = function(shop_id) {
        $('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
        $("#" + shop_id).tab('show');
    };
});
```

[From the doc:](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready."
>   jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside
>   $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object
>   Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use AngularJS to do the tab switch?

```
<a ng-href="#{{shop.slug}}" ng-bind="shop.name" ng-click="ctrl.switchTab(shop.id)"></a>
```

and

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" ng-repeat="shop in shops" ng-show="vm.currenTab==shop.id">
```

Then in your controller, have something like this:

```
$scope.vm = {
    currentTab: 0
};

$scope.ctrl = {
    switchTab: function(shop_id) {
        $scope.vm.currentTab = shop_id;
        // other code here
    }
};
```

Comment: what is the `vm`? Alias of the controller? Thanks, by the way.

Comment: I know this. But, I have other reasons to use jQuery.

Comment: vm = viewmodel, but it can be anything.

Comment: ow.. okay. Why do you think my jQuery is not working?

Comment: For one thing, you shouldn't put functions or properties directly into the $scope. You should have an object called "vm" (example) for your data and another called "ctrl" containing your methods. Concerning your problem, have you tried console.log(shop_id); in your method to see if the ID is valid?

Comment: yes.. `console.log(shop_id)` is working. The `id` is actually a slug.